# solve the system a+b=m(a-b), a*b=n(a-b)

Tags: systems-of-equations

given the following statement: the sum of 2 numbers namely 'a' and 'b' is equal to 'm' times their difference, and the product of those 2 numbers is 'n' times their difference.

we get the system:

```
a+b=m(a-b)
a*b=n(a-b)
```

and I'm able to decompose it like:

```
a+b=ma-mb
a*b=na-nb
.........
a=m(a-b)-b
b=m(a-b)-a
a=n(a-b)/b
b=n(a-b)/a
```

now, I know the answer is of the form:

```
a = 2n/m-1 and b = 2n/m+1
```

how is the process to solve this system of equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
4ab &=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\\
4n(a-b) & =(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\\
&= m^2(a-b)^2-(a-b)^2\\
&= (m^2-1)(a-b)^2\\
\implies (a-b) &=\dfrac{4n}{m^2-1} \text{, as obviously $a \ne b$}\\
\end{align}

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: you can have $a=b=0$, but ok, this is easy to treat this case separately.

Comment: That would be too trivial

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $b=ka$ then the first equation gives you $k=\frac{m-1}{m+1}$ and proceed to solve the second equation.

When you have some equations like this, it is often useful to test things like $b=ka$ our $b=a+k$ and see if you can get something out of it.